# Discord.Js disconnect members voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am currently working on my first discord.js bot. I wanted to make a command where the bot disconnects all members from the voice channel. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through every member in a voice channel using [`Collection.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) and [`VoiceState.kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=kick)

```js
// iterate a function through every member in a voice chat
<VoiceChannel>.members.each((member) => {
   member.voice.kick() // kick the member
};
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping, but when the but tries to kick the members, its gives me an error ;/ `(node:9528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined`

Comment: How did you define `VoiceChannel`?

Comment: `    if(command === 'scream') {
            const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
            const { voice } = msg.member

            if (!voice.channelID) {
                message.reply('You have to be in a VC!')
                return
            }

            await voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
                connection.play(path.join(__dirname, 'audio1.mp3'))
            })
            await delay(13500);
            voice.channel.leave()
    }`

Comment: Are you successfully joining and leaving the voice channel?

Comment: the bot is joining and leaving the vc so yes